# For loop to match names from lists: Why won't my values match?

Tags: python, pandas, python-re

I am trying to append matched names between a list (clients) and a dataframe (names). Unfortunately, I keep getting an error and am unsure what I am doing incorrectly. It references my line with the 'search' variable but I am having trouble understanding why it is saying the 'the Lengths must match'. When I have created a variable such as this in the past for similar purposes I have not gotten this error. Additionally, I tried a couple of modifications from my interpretation of the regex documentation and similar web results but they did not work out.

My code:

```
## example data
clients = [['Example Name'],['Example Name2']]
name_list = [['Example Name'],['Example Name1'],['Example Name2']]
names = pd.DataFrame(data=name_list,columns=['name'])

## code
matches = []
for client in clients:
    search = str(names.loc[names['name']==client,'name'].iloc[0])
    client_ = str(client)
    
    if re.search(client_,search,flags=re.IGNORECASE).group(0)== client_:
        matches.append(client)
    else:
        continue
print(matches)
```

Error Outputs:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[29], line 7
      5 matches = []
      6 for client in clients:
----> 7     search = str(names.loc[names['name']==client,'name'].iloc[0])
      8     client_ = str(client)
     10     if re.search(client_,search,flags=re.IGNORECASE).group(0)== client_:
```

`ValueError: ('Lengths must match to compare', (3,), (1,))`

**UPDATE FOR CLARIFICATION:** Thank you for the help, Raphael.

So I used example strings (ex. ['Example Name'] in name_list)for the dataframe for the original, below is the dataframe I want to search.

search_df print-out:

```
       Assessment Year      County  \
0                 2020  Atlantic     
1                 2022  Atlantic     
2                 2016  Atlantic     
3                 2016  Atlantic     
4                 2017  Atlantic     
      

                                              defendants  \
0                                           ABSECON CITY   
1                                                ABSECON   
2                                          ATLANTIC CITY   
3                                          ATLANTIC CITY   
4      CITY OF ATLANTIC CITY, A MUNICIPAL CORPORATION...   
   

                                              plaintiffs  
0                                        SSN ABSECON LLC  
1                                           RATAN AC LLC  
2                                              MAC CORP.  
3                                    GRAND PRIX ATLANTIC  
4      MAC CORP., A CORPORATION OF THE STATE OF NEW J...
```

I changed my approach since the original question from using a dataframe to just converting the column of interest to a list. I also switched from `re.search()` to using the `in` operand as it cannot read the list objects nor did it return a match when I concatenated the list to a single string:

```
search_list = []
for plaintiff in search_df['plaintiffs']:
    search_list.append([plaintiff])
```

the `client_list` has more names but for now know this value is within:
`SSN ABSECON, LLC`

So for example, when I perform this

```
for client in client_list:
    client_ = str(client).upper()
    print(client_)
    print(client_ in search_list)
print(search_list)
```

I receive this output:

```
['SSN ABSECON LLC']
False
...# I removed the other falses for brievity
...
[['SSN ABSECON LLC'],...etc.],
```

Which is confusing me because I made the appropriate case format, spacing, and string character modification to the search_list's should-be match in the client_list and it still is failing to return `True`. Let me know if you see what steps I am failing to do or if there is a better way.

Comment: We need your data to reproduce your issue.

Comment: What datatype is `names`? I assume a pandas dataframe?
I don't quite understand what you want to do in line 11, can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Maybe try `search = str(names[names['name']==client]['names'].values[0])`

Comment: @Raphael I am trying to use .loc to store the value as a string variable to use as the search string for re.search(). I have stored .loc values in variables before so I was surprised to see an issue relating to that line. I also updated the question to include some sample data (and updated error messages).

Comment: This might be because clients is an array of arrays. So you're comparing a string to an array with a single string. Try `names['name']==client[0]` Also check how the data is actually loaded into your dataframe, you might have some weird thing with nested arrays and such.

Comment: @Raphael Thanks so much for your help btw, I appreciate the aid. I tried your suggest. Unfortunately, I received this error `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().` I then tried the following `
 matches = []
for client in clients:
    client_ = str(client)
    if str(names.loc[names['name']==client[0],'name'].iloc[0])==client_:
        matches.append(client)
    else:
        continue
print(matches) ` which produced no error but did not append anything to matches. Do you have ideas why it would not append these?

Comment: Hm, could you just print the dataframe and include that output in the question?

Comment: @Raphael Thank you for the continued help. I posted the df and what i am currently trying. Let me know if there is any further clarifying data I can provide.

Comment: @JeffGordon hey I posted an answer with what I belive a solution to your problem, can ou test it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I had some time to play around and I think i got it working.
I changed the clients from `clients = [['SSN ABSECON LLC'], ["MAC CORP."]]`
to `clients = ['SSN ABSECON LLC', "MAC CORP."]` and converted the dataframe column to a list.

```py
import pandas as pd
import re

names = {"Assessment Year":[2020,2022,2016,2016,2017],"County":["Atlantic","Atlantic","Atlantic","Atlantic","Atlantic"],
        "defendants":["ABSECON CITY","ABSECON",  "ATLANTIC CITY","ATLANTIC CITY","CITY OF ATLANTIC CITY, A MUNICIPAL CORPORATION "],
        "plaintiffs":["SSN ABSECON LLC","RATAN AC LLC","MAC CORP.","GRAND PRIX ATLANTIC","MAC CORP., A CORPORATION OF THE STATE OF NEW J..."]
}
clients = ['SSN ABSECON LLC', "MAC CORP."]
names = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(names)

## code
matches = []
for client in clients:

    client_ = str(client).upper()
    print(client_)
    print(client_ in list(names["plaintiffs"]))
```

This prints:

```
SSN ABSECON LLC
True
MAC CORP.
True
```

I hope this does what you wanted.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I appreciate the aid!